# Will moss affect my indoor rubber trees?

Tags: indoors, moss, ficus

I've recently found moss growing very prettily in my outdoor pots, which I haven't paid much attention to over winter. I don't expect it'll do very well in summer out there, but I have *Ficus elastica* growing indoors and the bare soil isn't very attractive.

Can I transplant the moss around the rubber trees? I only water them about twice a week in summer and once a week in winter. Will that be enough water for the moss? Will the two species interact negatively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixus elastica is native to humid climate, therefore it makes good friends with moss.

As for the moss, it depends on the indoor humidity a lot. If you have powerful heating, which dries the air, the moss won’t grow well. So if your towels easily get completely dry indoors, it’s probably not the best for mosses.

Anyway, it’s a good idea to make an experiment!